# Dropbox oAuth2 redirectURL

Tags: c#, rest, oauth-2.0, win-universal-app, dropbox-api

I have not been working with REST for very long, I have dropbox authenticating in my app but why do I need a redirectURL? All I want to do is save the token from the response, although I am getting the following exception in the oAuthResponse:

```
exception = {"The supplied uri doesn't contain a fragment\r\nParameter name: redirectedUri"}
```

This is my redirect URL: https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/redirect_receiver

Comment: It seems your request URL doesn't have "redirect_uri" parameter. Can you give me your full request URL?

Comment: You need to listen for redirects which will happen several times during a login. check the target of the redirect and if it is your redirect url, then it will conatain the token. Your redirect url does not need to be a real location.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I was checking the response on every browser navigation start however my redirect_uri was set to the same as the other redirects in the Auth phase. All sorted not, cheers.